# create keyboard shortcut to SHIFT+ALT+. [dot character]

Tags: vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts

creating windows shortcut [.lnk file] programatically, but if keyboard combination is SHIFT+ALT+. [dot char]

`oShellLink.Hotkey = "SHIFT+ALT+."`

than vbs file display error

`CreateShortcut.vbs(12, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument`

when replace dot by alphabetical character, it works fine. Manually [via GUI] I am able to create working shortcut with dot char succesfully. Do I need to escape dot character in VBS file, or something else? Found nothihng about it...

Comment: As stated on https://ss64.com/vb/shortcut.html and https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshortcut-hotkey.html - "Valid hot key-options:
`"ALT+"`, `"CTRL+"`, `"SHIFT+"`, and `"EXT+"`.
`"A"` .. `"Z"`, `"0"` .. `"9"`, `"Back"`, `"Tab"`, `"Clear"`, `"Return"`, `"Escape"`, `"Space"`, and `"Prior"`.".

Comment: from where comming this "list of valid options"? I have succesfully created shortcut CTRL+ALT+UP ARROW  resp. DOWN ARROW by VBS, so doubting about this list...

Comment: And yet the script fails when you use `.`. It might not be a complete list or `UP` (on a numpad equates to `8`) refers to the numpad but anyway it's clear `.` is not supported.

Comment: dot is not supported only by VBS? Because shortcut cteared by GUI accept dot char and it work fine. So there are differences between shortcuts defined by VBS and by GUI?

Comment: Yes, it would appear that is the case as I came to the same conclusion with my own testing of a Windows Shortcut and a VBScript one.